# Awk access variable more than once

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to access a variable defined in awk multiple times, but it does not seem to work.

Lets assume we have a `data.txt` with contents:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

If we do awk with:

```
cat data.txt | awk 'sum=($1+$2), div1=(sum/$1) {print " sum: " sum " div1: " div1 " data: " $0}'
```

It works fine and we get an output of

```
sum: 3 div1: 3 data: 1 2
sum: 5 div1: 2.5 data: 2 3
sum: 7 div1: 2.33333 data: 3 4
```

If I try to access the `sum` multiple times, I get an error

```
cat data.txt | awk 'sum=($1+$2), div1=(sum/$1), div2=(sum/$2) {print " sum: " sum " div1: " div1 " div2: " div2 " data: " $0}'
```

Even if I change `div2=(sum/$2)` to `div1=(sum/$1)`, which is exactly the same as before, I will still get the error:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
```

How can I get around this issue and access any specific variable assigned in awk to be accessible multiple times?

Comment: You should be using `awk '{sum=$1+$2; div1=sum/$1; div2=sum/$2; print "sum:", sum, "div1:", div1, "div2:", div2, "data:", $0}' data.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part before the `{}` block is supposed to be a condition. Put variable assignments inside the `{}`. Multiple statements are separated using `;`.

```
cat data.txt | awk '{sum=($1+$2); div1=(sum/$1); div2=(sum/$2); print " sum: " sum " div1: " div1 " div2: " div2 " data: " $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing comma separated assignments and cleaning it further:

```bash
awk '{sum=$1+$2; print "sum:", sum, "div1:", sum/$1, "div2:", sum/$2, "data:", $0}' data.txt

sum: 3 div1: 3 div2: 1.5 data: 1 2
sum: 5 div1: 2.5 div2: 1.66667 data: 2 3
sum: 7 div1: 2.33333 div2: 1.75 data: 3 4
```

For more control over floating point formatting and spacing etc use `printf` or `OFMT` like this:

```bash
awk -v OFMT='%.2g' '{sum=$1+$2; print "sum:", sum, "div1:", sum/$1, "div2:", sum/$2, "data:", $0}' data.txt

sum: 3 div1: 3 div2: 1.5 data: 1 2
sum: 5 div1: 2.5 div2: 1.7 data: 2 3
sum: 7 div1: 2.3 div2: 1.8 data: 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

*technically*, you can do it entire in the pattern space too, just less elegant :

> ```
> mawk '($4=($3=___=(_=$1)+(__=$+2))\
>                   /_/(1 + 4^-5^2)) \
>           ($5=___/__/(1 + 4^-5^2))_' CONVFMT='%.10f' OFS='\t'
> ```

```
1    2    3    3.0000000000    1.5000000000
2    3    5    2.5000000000    1.6666666667
3    4    7    2.3333333333    1.7500000000
```

The extra bit of `2^-50` is to force floating point output,
-- but since it's also far beyond the output precision level, the chance of it affecting the output is miniscule -- `TL;DR` adding something *near* `precision epsilon`